# How do I make different targets build to separate iOS applications?

Tags: xcode, ios, projects

I have a project with two different versions.  I keep two targets in xcode to differentiate the two.  Are there steps I need to take to submit them as two separate apps, like changing the bundle identifier from this default value that has a suffix of "`${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}`"?

I'd like to be able to build the executable to my iPad and have two separate apps, but every time I build, flavor 1 and 2 of the app just overwrite each other instead of creating two separate apps.  How can I make them build separately, and does the current state of my project mean I will have problems submitting it as two separate apps unless I make some config changes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the inspector for each target, select the Properties tab and set a unique bundle identifier. iOS differentiates apps by their bundle identifiers, which is why they are overwriting each other on your device. iTunes Connect also relies on bundle identifiers, so every app on the App Store has a unique bundle identifier.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I looked further and it seems I also needed to change the Product Name setting in order for the ___.app file to be different between the two.